# avoid null pointer excpetion while parsing the xml

Tags: java

This is my xml to parse

```
<metadata>
    <groupId>org.chromium</groupId>
    <artifactId>chromedriver-win32</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <release>2.14</release>
        <versions>
            <version>2.14</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20150610112540</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

While I am trying to parse the above XML, I am getting `NullPointerException` even though I have handled the null check. Below is the code

```
private String getVersionFromNode(Element eElement) {
    String version = null;

    // Get the latest version
    String tagName = "latest";
    try {
        version = eElement.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0).getTextContent();
        // If latest version is not available take the release
        // version
        if ( version.isEmpty() ||  null == version || "null" == version) {
            tagName = "release";
            version = eElement.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0).getTextContent();
        }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
       System.out.println("not able to parse " + tagName + " tag " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return version;
}
```

When the version is null, it should enter in below block.

```
if ( version.isEmpty() ||  null == version || "null" == version) {
    tagName = "release";
    version = eElement.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0).getTextContent();

}
```

What should be solution for this problem?

Comment: You are getting the tag called "latest" or "release". Can't see that names in your XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `String tagName` is `"latest"` and in your xml file, there is no element named `latest` and so your `version` remains `null` and therefore a `NullPointerException` is generated when the code:

```
version.isEmpty()
```

is executed in your `if` statement. Because `version` is `null`. And your code tries to check if `null` is empty. Which it cannot. And so, a `NullPointerException` is generated here.

To handle this situation, first check if `version` is `null`. Secondly check if the string `version` is equal to string `"null"`. And thirdly check if it is empty. So change the sequence of conditions in your `if` statement from:

```
if ( version.isEmpty() ||  null == version || "null" == version)
```

to

```
if (null == version || "null" == version || version.isEmpty())
```

By the way, as a side tip, use:

```
"null".equals(version)
```

rather than

```
"null" == version
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your condition

```
if ( version.isEmpty() ||  null == version || "null" == version)
```

to

```
if (null == version || "null".equals(version) || version.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 1):

When chaining together method calls, you risk a `NullPointerException` at every step. For example, in your line

```
version = eElement.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0).getTextContent();
```

there are 4 opportunities for a `NullPointerException`:

- if `eElement` is null, trying to call `getElementsByTagName(tagName)`
- if calling getElementsByTagName(tagName) when tagName is null
- if `getElementsByTagName(tagName)` returns null, trying to call `item(0)`
- if `item(0)` returns null, trying to call `getTextContent()`

Not all of these will be possible in your code because `tagName` is specified, but you should always beware.

An alternative approach for your problem would be to use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

See also [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)